# Deploy Nuxt.js on AWS elastic beanstalk through Codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nuxt.js, aws-codebuild

I am trying to deploy Nuxt.js application to EBS through codepipeline and codebuild.
The code is successfully build in codebuild and deployed to EBS.
It keeping failing on running Procfile commands which is: `node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 start`

I exported the full log from EBS and found out the PM2 comment was running successfully. Systemd was jumped in and said `systemd: web.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.` It end up with a endless loop.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.